# Laravel collection opposite of diff

Tags: laravel, diff, laravel-collection

i have 2 collections:

```
$collection = collect([1,2,3,4]);
$collection2 = collect([1,5,6,4]);
```

with:

```
$collection->diff($collection2);
```

i get `[2,3]`

so what i want is to have the opposite value, `[1,4]`

Is there a way or method in collection to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use duplicates method after mergging into single collection

```
$collection1 = collect([1,2,3,4]);
$collection2 = collect([1,5,6,4]);

$duplicates = $collection1
  ->merge($collection2)
  ->duplicates()
  ->values();
```

Will give you

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1151
     all: [
       1,
       4,
     ],
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

laravel collection [intersect](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-intersect)

intersect method removes any values from the original collection that are not present in the given array or collection.

```
$collection = collect([1,2,3,4]);
$collection2 = collect([1,5,6,4]);

$intersect = $collection->intersect($collection2);

$intersect->all();
```